# pry: artifacts on ctrl-arrow (ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, readline, pry

I installed ruby using rvm and I use it in a RoR project. the problem is that when I start `pry` inside that project, I'm not able to use ctrl-arrows shortcuts> Instead of getting a word left/right, it prints artifacts, like `;5D` or `;5C`. When I call `pry` outside of that project, everything is OK. ctrl-arrows works also in the regular console. I've already tried to reinstall readline and ruby with readline support. What could I do more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the problem. I had `rb-readline` dependency in my `Gemfile`. Once I removed it, the problems disappeared.

Comment: any ideas why this is caused?

Comment: i am running into the same issue, and am not sure how to resolve it?

Comment: this bugs seems the cause: https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/rb-readline/issues/105

Comment: and this pull request solves it :) https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/rb-readline/pull/125

Answer (score 4):

One way to fix this is to create a `.inputrc` in your home directory with the following content:

```
"\033[1;5C": forward-word
"\033[1;5D": backward-word
```

I had this issue with both bash and pry and the above fixed it for me.

Note that the `"\033[1;5C"` seems to vary depending on your operating system - or possibly the terminal software you're using. On OSX you can see what instruction actually gets generated when you press ctrl-right by going to the Settings dialog of Terminal.app, selecting a profile, and clicking the 'keyboard' tab:

- On Snow Leopard the default is `\033[5D`
- On Mavericks the default is `\033[1;5C`

This issue happens because the instructions sent by your terminal aren't recognised by your shell (? bear with me - the following is largely guesswork based on my googling)

Here's how those codes break down:

`\033` is the octal representation of the ASCII [Escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). It means "interpret what follows as instructions for manipulating the terminal - not as text". It can also be represented in other ways depending on the context, including:

- in hexadecimal as `^[` (e.g. `^[[1;5D`)
- in bash as `\e` (e.g. `\e[5D` or `\e\e[D`)

I think the `1` just means 'do this operation on the same line as the cursor, and the `5D` is intended to be interpreted as 'skip forward one word'. The `;` just separates the two instructions.

My guess is that issue comes from some shells or utilities either not natively understanding that `5D` is supposed to mean 'skip one word', or not supporting composing instructions with `;`. Adding an `.inputrc` fills in the blanks and makes everything work :)